# bootstrap carousel stretch image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

this is bootstrap carousel, i tried to use col-xs-12 or sm to make it smaller and fitted to smaller screens. but it seems becomes stretch images of my carousel how to make it in normal size?

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active" contenteditable="false"></li>
         <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
     </ol>
     <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item" style="">
             <img src="images/wallpapers/3iK5Pf1.jpg" alt="first-img" class="img-responsive col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
             <div class="carousel-caption">
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="item active">
             <img src="images/wallpapers/3iK5Pf.jpg" alt="second-img" class="img-responsive col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
             <div class="carousel-caption">
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="item" style="">
             <img src="images/wallpapers/3iK5Pf2.jpg" alt="third-img" class="img-responsive col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
             <div class="carousel-caption">
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>    

     <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
     </a>

     <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
     </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try to call "col-xs-12 col-sm-12" these class in upper div of img tag. like

Ex:

```
<div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="">
            <img src="images/wallpapers/3iK5Pf1.jpg" alt="first-img" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please Give Proper Response if your question answered.

Comment: As Bootstrap is mobile first, there is no need of `col-sm-12` class if there is `col-xs-12` class is already applied on the same div.